# Drupal 9, filter two views on single page based on same filters

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, facet, drupal-9

There is one page containing a view for doctor listing which gets filtered based on the facets. Two facets are "Speciality" and "Location". Thse two fields are tagged in the doctor contents.
We also have similar tagging for content "FAQ". How can I display the Specific FAQs on same page with the filter applied.

**doctor listing path :** /doctors

**hospital filter:** /doctors/hospital/[hospital_slug]-[hospital_node_id]
*/doctors/hospital/xyz-hospitals-1234*

**speciality filter:** /doctors/speciality/[speciality_slug]-[node_id]
*/doctors/speciality/heart-surgery-1450*

**both filters:** /doctors/hospital/[hospital_slug]-[hospital_node_id]/speciality/[speciality_slug]-[node_id]

Tried adding a view for FAQ but its displaying all the faqs and not filtering based on filters. We already have a filter page for FAQs to where it gets filtered based on similar filters, I duplicated that view  but same problem.

**I'm new to drupal**

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is not that you want two views, but rather that you want to have one view which shows the Doctor (or hospital?) along with the associated FAQs for that doctor/hospital.

Since it sounds like the FAQs and the doctor/hospital share a taxonomy reference field, what you would want to do is utilize a relationship to link the doctor/hospital to the associated FAQs.

See https://drupalize.me/tutorial/overview-relationships-views.